# Wine: is my system secure to use again?

Tags: wine, security, malware, hacking

I installed wine latest version ,on my 16.04 .then I installed an untrusted exe which could have been a virus as it might have caused the registry error on my windows 10 earlier today
So I uninstalled the program from wine and then purged wine it's derivatives and the config files along with exe files all over the pc .
As I am security paranoid i want reassurance that a virus is still not there.reinsalling Ubuntu will be tough as I have a lot of customisations.

Comment: did you run the malicious executable on a parrallel installation of windows 10 or just in your wineprefix?

Comment: On a windows 10 dualboot

Comment: But I ran in my Ubuntu as well

Comment: Your windows should not be able to access your ubuntu partitions because of extfs, right? As for wine: depending on what exactly the executable does, deleting the wineprefix should be sufficient in most cases

Comment: I have deleted my windows partition and wineprix as well so a confirmation of security from even the most innovative exploits (eg by spreading to my Linux home partition or system files )

Comment: A virus spreading to parallel installations of linux is possible but highly unlikely. But if you want to be 100% sure you'll have to purge your hard drive completely.

Comment: But if I removed wine it neutralises the virus right?

Comment: It's a percentages game - I would say so with 95%+ certainty

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and I think I will go with the odds and use this same installation